# The image is shrinking on smaller devices

Tags: css, image, next.js, tailwind-css

I am randomly generating quotes using an api. I want to put that quote into my topbar but when I added it and checked mobile view , In smaller quotes it shows normal but in case of larger quotes, it shrinks the profile image present at left of my topbar. So please help to solve it.

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9xp7.png)

Generating Quote

```
const [quote,setQuote] = useState("")

   useEffect(() => {
fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    setQuote(data[Math.floor(Math.random() * 1643) + 1].text);
    console.log("Quote"+quote)
  });
   }, []);
```

TopBar

```
     <div
    classname={`fixed w-full h-16 flex justify-between items-center transition-all duration-[400ms] ${
        showNav ? "pl-56" : ""
      }`}
    >
      <div className="pl-4 md:pl-16">
        <Bars3CenterLeftIcon
          className="h-8 w-8 text-gray-700 cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => setShowNav(!showNav)}
        />
      </div>
      <h1 className="mx-4 text-sm">{quote}</h1>
      <div className="flex items-center pr-4 md:pr-16">
        <Popover className="relative">
          <Popover.Button className="outline-none mr-5 md:mr-8 cursor-pointer text-gray-700">
            <BellIcon className="h-6 w-6" />
          </Popover.Button>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
            enterFrom="transform scale-95"
            enterTo="transform scale-100"
            leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
            leaveFrom="transform scale-100"
            leaveTo="transform scale-95"
          >
            <Popover.Panel className="absolute -right-16 sm:right-4 z-50 mt-2 bg-white shadow-sm rounded max-w-xs sm:max-w-sm w-screen">
              <div className="relative p-3">
                <div className="flex justify-between item-center w-full">
                  <p className="text-gray-700 font-medium">Notifications</p>
                  <a className="text-sm text-orange-500" href="#">
                    Mark all as read
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-4 grid gap-4 grid-cols-1 overflow-hidden">
                  <div className="flex">
                    <div className="rounded-full shrink-0 bg-green-200 h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center">
                      <CheckIcon className="w-4 h-4 text-green-600" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="ml-4">
                      <p className="font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Notification Title
                      </p>
                      <p className="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">
                        Text Notification text for design
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex">
                    <div className="rounded-full shrink-0 bg-green-200 h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center">
                      <CheckIcon className="w-4 h-4 text-green-600" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="ml-4">
                      <p className="font-medium text-gray-700">
                        Notification Title
                      </p>
                      <p className="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">
                        Text Notification text for design
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Popover.Panel>
          </Transition>
        </Popover>
        <Menu as={"div"} className="relative inline-block text-left">
          <div>
            <Menu.Button
              className={"inline-flex w-full justify-center items-center"}
            >
              <picture>
                <img
                  src="/man smiling.jpg"
                  alt="Profile picture"
                  className="rounded-full h-8 md:mr-4 bottom-2 border-white shadow-sm"
                />
              </picture>
              <span className="hidden md:block font-medium text-gray-700">
                Rettson
              </span>
              <ChevronDownIcon className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 text-gray-700" />
            </Menu.Button>
          </div>
          <Transition
            as={Fragment}
            enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
            enterFrom="transform scale-95"
            enterTo="transform scale-100"
            leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
            leaveFrom="transform scale-100"
            leaveTo="transform scale-95"
          >
            <Menu.Items
              className={
                "absolute right-0 w-56 z-50 mt-2 origin-top-right bg-white rounded shadow-sm"
              }
            >
              <div className="p-1">
                <Menu.Item>
                  <Link
                    href={"#"}
                    className="flex hover:bg-orange-500 hover:text-white text-gray-700 rounded p-2 text-sm group transition-colors items-center"
                  >
                    <PencilIcon className="h-4 w-4 mr-2" />
                    Edit
                  </Link>
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item>
                  <Link
                    href={"#"}
                    className="flex hover:bg-orange-500 hover:text-white text-gray-700 rounded p-2 text-sm group transition-colors items-center"
                  >
                    <CreditCardIcon className="h-4 w-4 mr-2" />
                    Billing
                  </Link>
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item>
                  <Link
                    href={"#"}
                    className="flex hover:bg-orange-500 hover:text-white text-gray-700 rounded p-2 text-sm group transition-colors items-center"
                  >
                    <Cog8ToothIcon className="h-4 w-4 mr-2" />
                    Settings
                  </Link>
                </Menu.Item>
              </div>
            </Menu.Items>
          </Transition>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    </div>
```

layout.js for showNav

````
import { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import SideBar from './SideBar'
import TopBar from './TopBar'
import { Transition } from "@headlessui/react";

export default function Layout({children}) {
    const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(true)
    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false)

    function handleResize() {
        if (innerWidth <= 640) {
            setShowNav(false)
            setIsMobile(true)
        } else {
            setShowNav(true)
            setIsMobile(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window != undefined) {
            addEventListener("resize",handleResize)
        }
        
        return () => {
            removeEventListener("resize",handleResize)
        }
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <>
            <TopBar showNav={showNav} setShowNav={setShowNav} />
            <Transition
                as={Fragment}
                show={showNav}
                enter="transform transition duration-[400ms]"
                enterFrom="-translate-x-full"
                enterTo="translate-x-0"
                leave="transform duration-[400ms] transition ease-in-out"
                leaveFrom="translate-x-0"
                leaveTo='-translate-x-full'
            >
                <SideBar showNav={showNav} />
            </Transition>
            <main className={`pt-16 transition-all duration-[400ms] ${showNav && !isMobile ? "pl-56" : ""}`}>
                <div className="px-4 md:px-16">
                    {children}
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}```

Here profile image is shrinking when bigger quote comes

I tried changing the width of quote, but it seems to have no effect
````

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It doesn't make sense to ask us to grub inside your repo. Just show us the relevant piece of code. It would be nice if you can use [Tailwind-CSS Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/)

Comment: added codesandbox link

Comment: @AlonEitan why??

Comment: SO requests that the code should be within the actual question because it is aiming to build up a repository of questions and answers which will be useful not just for you but for future readers. The problem with things like an external sandbox is that they may get deleted at any time or the code corrected. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For the reason why, see also the "_Help others reproduce the problem_" in [ask].

Comment: Add a width to the img `className` - for example `<img className="w-8 h-8"`

Comment: Try to add a definite width like `w-12` or anything to the component where you are populating the quote for small screen and `sm:w-full` for other breakpoints. Another option is to add `overflow-scroll-x` class to that component.